# rowCount não retorna zero

Tags: php, pdo

Tenho esse script:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST)){
$user = isset($_POST['user']) ? strip_tags($_POST['user']) : 'HabboColorFS';
$rank = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM topicos_comentarios WHERE autor='".$user."'")->rowCount();
$usuario = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='".$user."'");
$usuario->execute();
    while($ver = $usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
<?php print $usuario->rowCount(); ?>
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $cx_uploads; ?>/<?php echo $ver['avatar']; ?>')">
<div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $rank; ?></div>
<div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;123</div>
<div class="base">
    <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?&user=<?php echo $ver['usuario']; ?>&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&img_format=png&gesture=std&headonly=0&size=s')"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="type day">
<div class="totype"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true">
</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;RANKING DO DIA</div>
<div class="position">178º</div>
</div>
<div class="type all">
<div class="totype"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true">
</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;RANKING GERAL</div>
<div class="position">178º</div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Estou tentando fazer um if que quando $usuario->rowCount() for 0 ele exibir uma mensagem de erro "echo "nenhum usuário encontrado"".

Coloquei print $usuario->rowCount(); e tentei com echo tbm, já fiz o if dessa forma, porem quando faço uma busca proposital para que dê vazio ele não exibe o 0.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Já tentou colocar o `rowCount` fora do `while` em que você faz o `fetch`?

Comment: Nossa, deu certo! kkkk. Obrigado, sabe me explicar porque só funciona fora?

Comment: Porquê o método `fetch` retornará `false` quando não houver registros e, nesse caso, não é executado o `while`.

Comment: Entendido! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não será exibido na tela que há zeros registros no banco de dados porquê o instrução de exibição deste valor:

```
print $usuario->rowCount();
```

Está dentro de um loop:

```
while($ver = $usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {...}
```

Olhando a documentação do método [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php), há a seguinte descrição de retorno:

> *The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.*

O valor retornado dependerá do parâmetro definido, em caso de sucesso, ou FALSE em qualquer outro caso. Sendo o número de registros nulo, o método retornará `false` e, portanto, o loop não será executado. Se você deseja mesmo exibir a quantidade de registros, mesmo que seja zero, basta colocar o `print` fora do loop:

```
print $usuario->rowCount();

while($ver = $usuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```